Next.js client/server components naming convention
Sometimes the client-server relationships might be a bit vague with nextjs' app router, with abstracts especially.
What approach do you use to distinguish client and server files/components?
List.server.tsx and List.client.tsx?

Typically, I will just call the element a ServerList so the usage is very clear.

Just jumping in here, I was also thinking about this. My main issue is I seem to have quite a few components where I have an outer server component which basically immediately delegates to a client component (after fetching data/whatever it needs to do on the server).
I'm playing with this now:
// MyComponent.ts
export function MyComponent {
   ...
   return <MyComponentClient .../>
}

// MyComponent.client.ts
'use client'
export function MyComponentClient { 
   ...
}

In other words, adding .client in the filename and Client on the component (you could also just call the file MyComponentClient.tsx too, I just kind of like the .client to signify it's essentially "the same" component as the parent, just the client-side shifted bits).
"Client" is a bit overloaded but I prefer it to MyComponentInner etc which doesn't convey any meaning.
If a component is purely a client component/server component and doesn't have a corresponding server/client component I don't think there's any need to suffix the filename.
